# Как переопределить правила в css?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно переопределить правило в css?
Я задал стиль всем псевдоэлементам заголоаков, top: 50%, для боковой линии, чтоб она стояла сбоку по центру заголовка, теперь в одной секции мне нужно было переопределить такой же заголовок, сделать его bottom: 0; но стили не переопределяются, !important не помогает.

Вот код:

```
<section id="template" class="template">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Fully Supported template</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse malesuada sodales risus, a adipiscing lorem commodo vitae. Ut semper semper lacus. Suspendisse convallis vel tellus at consectetur. Aenean risus arcu</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Read more</a>
        </div>
    </section>


h2::before {
    content: "";
    background: #222;
    height: 2px;
    width: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
}

h2::after {
    content: "";
    background: #222;
    height: 2px;
    width: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Заголовок, который нужно переопределить

```
   .template h2::after {
        content: "";
        width: 350px;
        height: 2px;
        background: red;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: block;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно переопределить свойства `margin-left` и `position`

```css
h2::before {
  content: "";
  background: #222;
  height: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -150px;
}

h2::after {
  content: "";
  background: #222;
  height: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.template h2::after {
  content: "";
  width: 350px;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0;
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<section id="template" class="template">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Fully Supported template</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse malesuada sodales risus, a adipiscing lorem commodo vitae. Ut semper semper lacus. Suspendisse convallis vel tellus at consectetur. Aenean risus arcu</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Read more</a>
  </div>
</section>
```